# Circumscribe min diameter sphere around piece wise linear continuous curve

Tags: curves, spheres

I am looking for algorithm to circumscribe min diameter sphere around piece-wise linear continuous curve. Curve is in $\mathbb R^n$. I was thinking to find largest distance between points of the curve and use it as diameter, but it easy to see that equilateral triangle would have sphere with different center.